# zsh moving to parent directory with shift tab

Tags: zsh

How can you achieve in `zsh` that pressing `shift+tab` enters the parent directory AND updates/prints the new directory at the beginning of the cmd line?

Current situation/behaviour:

```
~ %         # pressing shift tab
~ %         # (it did change to parent dir, but it does not show that)
```

I want:

```
 ~ %        # pressing shift tab
/home %     # change to AND print 'new' directory
```

I use this code snippet:

```
function parent_dir { cd .. }
zle -N parent_dir
bindkey '^[[Z' parent_dir
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redraw your prompt, which can be done via the `reset-prompt` zle widget.

So, simply expand your `parent_dir` function to

```
function parent_dir {
  cd ..
  zle reset-prompt
}
```